# How install Swagger without Maven

Tags: maven, swagger

I am not Maven´s user and i want configure all dependencies of Swagger in my project. I try make it unsucessful. I get thousands jars, jackson-*, swagger-* and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-1.5.X#adding-the-dependencies-to-your-application:

> Projects that cannot utilize maven's dependencies would need to add
>   the dependencies manually. Since those may change from version to
>   version, the list of dependencies will not be documented here.
>   Instead, it is advised that you clone the swagger-core repository, go
>   to the directory of the relevant module (artifact) and run `mvn dependency:list`. That would give you a list of dependencies required
>   by swagger-core which you would have to include manually in your
>   application. Keep in mind this requires you to have maven installed
>   but it does not require you to use maven for your project.

Comment: If dependencies are downloaded; then what should one do? @Ron your answer is partial but helpful.