# Swagger for non Maven Java Projects

Tags: maven, swagger

I am planning to integrate Swagger to my existing non Maven Java Web Project with
JAX-RS and Jersey-1.X. Can someone help me out with the initial set up as to what dependencies - sawgger*jar files are needed to accomplish the feat.

As per the swagger's GitHub Page: its unclear to me as to what are the required libraries . [Please check this link.](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-1.5.X). **All the instructions here are purely Maven based.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How install Swagger without Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997718/how-install-swagger-without-maven)

Comment: As the post says, one needs to download a lot of jar files, and most of the attempts are unsuccessful. Is there any quick and easy way?

Comment: one quick and easy way is described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3601645/2012372), if you're willing to set up a dummy `pom.xml`

Comment: Hi greenSocksRock: Thanks for the comment. The next issue I ran into after the dependencies was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691330/error-404-for-swagger-json-swagger-yaml-non-maven